# Cохранение текста при закрытии программы

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Есть текстовый редактор. Как сделать так чтобы написанный текст в `RichTextBox` остался при закрытии программы? Если запустить программу снова, ранее написанный текст будет отображаться в `RichTextBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто на событие формы Closing привяжи сохранение текста в файл и точно так-же на Activated загрузку текста из файла в RichTextBox.

Comment: Может Deactivate? Closing нет.

Comment: Странно... тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx  вроде есть..